# How to disable Google Search?

Tags: battery-life, nexus-4

Recently my phone started to lose charge faster. It just occurred to me to check Battery in Settings, and I saw that Google Search is responsible for 29%, Screen coming in second with 23%.

I set up Google Now a few weeks back, is it the same thing?

If not, what exactly *is* Google Search? Is it something I actually use, and Google Search is just a collective name for them? Can I turn it off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Search is the package that contains both Google Search and Google Now. I think you can disable Google Now while keeping the search part by going into `Now->Settings->Switch Google Now (first item)`.

If it doesn't solves your problem, then you can disable Google Search in `Settings->Applications->Google Search->Disable`.